# Add border to the div that was clicked

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

I have an object with which to store some information.
To present this data, I used a * ngFor that creates a line for each instance.

Is there a way to add border when I click on one of these lines? The border should only be added to the line where it was clicked, if after clicking on another line, the border disappears from the previous line and appears in the current line.

How can I do this?

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wrpdy1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)

**.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of objects; let i = index" style="width: 100%;">
    <div class="d-flex flex-row divs">
        <div>
            <span>{{item.id}}</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <span>{{item.name}}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="margin-left:auto">
            <button>click</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `ngClass` to set the class dynamically based on the item you clicked.

for example :

```
<div class="d-flex flex-row divs" 
    [ngClass]="{'active' : (selectedItem.id === item.id)}"> <div>
  ...

</div>
```

Then on button click you can pass the item getting clicked :

```
<div style="margin-left:auto">
            <button (click)="setItem(item)">click</button>
        </div>
```

In `component.ts` file you can set the selected item as follow :

```
public selectedItem :any = {};

setItem(item){
  this.selectedItem = item
}
```

Now in css you can have `.active` class css as below :

```
.active{
  border : 1px solid red;
}
```

Here is the working example : [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kaa1qy).